# Qt - update view size on delegate sizeHint change

Tags: python, pyside2

I have a `QTreeView` with a `QStyledItemDelegate` inside of it. When a certain action occurs to the delegate, its size is supposed to change. However I haven't figured out how to get the `QTreeView`'s rows to resize in response to the delegate's editor size changing. I tried `QTreeView.updateGeometry` and `QTreeView.repaint` and a couple other things but it doesn't seem to work. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Here's a minimal reproduction (note: The code is hacky in a few places, it's just meant to be a demonstration of the problem, not a demonstration of good MVC).

Steps:

- Run the code below
- Press either "Add a label" button
- Note that the height of the row in the `QTreeView` does not change no matter how many times either button is clicked.

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets


_VALUE = 100


class _Clicker(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    clicked = QtCore.Signal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(_Clicker, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())

        self._button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Add a label")
        self.layout().addWidget(self._button)

        self._button.clicked.connect(self._add_label)
        self._button.clicked.connect(self.clicked.emit)

    def _add_label(self):
        global _VALUE

        _VALUE += 10

        self.layout().addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Add a label"))

        self.updateGeometry()  # Note: I didn't expect this to work but added it regardless


class _Delegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        widget = _Clicker(parent=parent)
        viewer = self.parent()

        widget.clicked.connect(viewer.updateGeometries)  # Note: I expected this to work

        return widget

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        super(_Delegate, self).paint(painter, option, index)

        viewer = self.parent()

        if not viewer.isPersistentEditorOpen(index):
            viewer.openPersistentEditor(index)

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        pass

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, option, index):
        editor.setGeometry(option.rect)

    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        hint = index.data(QtCore.Qt.SizeHintRole)

        if hint:
            return hint

        return super(_Delegate, self).sizeHint(option, index)


class _Model(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(_Model, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        self._labels = ["foo", "bar"]

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.SizeHintRole:
            return QtCore.QSize(200, _VALUE)

        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return None

        return self._labels[index.row()]

    def index(self, row, column, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        child = self._labels[row]

        return self.createIndex(row, column, child)

    def parent(self, index):
        return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if parent.isValid():
            return 0

        return len(self._labels)


application = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

view = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
view.setModel(_Model())
view.setItemDelegate(_Delegate(parent=view))
view.show()

application.exec_()
```

How do I get a single row in a `QTreeView`, which has a persistent editor applied already to it, to tell Qt to resize in response to some change in the editor?

Note: One possible solution would be to close the persistent editor and re-open it to force Qt to redraw the editor widget. This would be generally very slow and not work in my specific situation. Keeping the same persistent editor is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation about [`updateGeometries()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#updateGeometries) explains, it:

> Updates the geometry of the child widgets of the view.

This is used to update the widgets (editors, scroll bars, headers, etc) based on the current view state. It doesn't consider the editor size hints, so that call or the attempt to update the size hint is useless (and, it should go without saying, using global for this is wrong).

In order to properly notify the view that a specific index has updated its size hint, you must use the delegate's [`sizeHintChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemdelegate.html#sizeHintChanged) signal, which should also be emitted when the editor is created in order to ensure that the view makes enough room for it; note that this is normally not required for standard editors (as, being they temporary, they should *not* try to change the layout of the view), but for persistent editors that are potentially big, it may be necessary.

Other notes:

- calling `updateGeometry()` on the widget is pointless in this case, as adding a widget to a layout automatically results in a `LayoutRequest` event (which is what `updateGeometry()` does, among other things);
- as explained in [`createEditor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemdelegate.html#createEditor), "the view's background will shine through unless the editor paints its own background (e.g., with setAutoFillBackground())";
- the `SizeHintRole` of the model should always return a size important for the model (if any), *not* based on the editor; it's the delegate responsibility to do that, and the model should never be influenced by any of its views;
- opening a persistent editor in a paint event is wrong; only drawing related aspects should ever happen in a paint function, most importantly because they are called very often (even hundreds of times per second for item views) so they should be as fast as possible, but also because doing anything that might affect a change in geometry will cause (at least) a recursive call;
- signals can be "chained" without using `emit`: `self._button.clicked.connect(self.clicked)` would have sufficed;

Considering all the above, there are two possibilities. The problem is that there is no direct correlation between the editor widget and the index it's referred to, so we need to find a way to emit `sizeHintChanged` with its correct index when the editor is updated.
This can only be done by creating a reference of the index for the editor, but it's important that we use a [QPersistentModelIndex](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpersistentmodelindex.html) for that, as the indexes might change while a persistent editor is opened (for example, when sorting or filtering), and the index provided in the arguments of delegate functions is not able to track these changes.

### Emit a custom signal

In this case, we only use a custom signal that is emitted whenever we know that the layout is changed, and we create a local function in `createEditor` that will eventually emit the `sizeHintChanged` signal by "reconstructing" the valid index:

```
class _Clicker(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    sizeHintChanged = QtCore.Signal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self._button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Add a label")
        layout.addWidget(self._button)

        self._button.clicked.connect(self._add_label)

    def _add_label(self):
        self.layout().addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Add a label"))
        self.sizeHintChanged.emit()


class _Delegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        widget = _Clicker(parent)
        persistent = QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(index)

        def emitSizeHintChanged():
            index = persistent.model().index(
                persistent.row(), persistent.column(), 
                persistent.parent())
            self.sizeHintChanged.emit(index)

        widget.sizeHintChanged.connect(emitSizeHintChanged)
        self.sizeHintChanged.emit(index)
        return widget

    # no other functions implemented here
```

### Use the delegate's event filter

We can create a reference for the persistent index in the editor, and then emit the `sizeHintChanged` signal in the event filter of the delegate whenever a `LayoutRequest` event is received from the editor:

```
class _Clicker(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self._button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Add a label")
        layout.addWidget(self._button)

        self._button.clicked.connect(self._add_label)

    def _add_label(self):
        self.layout().addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Add a label"))


class _Delegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        widget = _Clicker(parent)
        widget.index = QtCore.QPersistentModelIndex(index)
        return widget

    def eventFilter(self, editor, event):
        if event.type() == event.LayoutRequest:
            persistent = editor.index
            index = persistent.model().index(
                persistent.row(), persistent.column(), 
                persistent.parent())
            self.sizeHintChanged.emit(index)
        return super().eventFilter(editor, event)
```

---

Finally, you should obviously remove the `SizeHintRole` return in `data()`, and in order to open all persistent editors you could do something like this:

```
def openEditors(view, parent=None):
    model = view.model()
    if parent is None:
        parent = QtCore.QModelIndex()
    for row in range(model.rowCount(parent)):
        for column in range(model.columnCount(parent)):
            index = model.index(row, column, parent)
            view.openPersistentEditor(index)
            if model.rowCount(index):
                openEditors(view, index)

# ...
openEditors(view)
```

Comment: I learned a lot in this post, thank you for detailing it so thoroughly! FWIW some of the points I mentioned earlier are parts of the hacky bits that I mentioned in the initial post. That said, I wasn't aware of some of the reasons so this has been really helpful. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when I was adding new widgets to a QFrame, because the dumb thing was not updating the value of its `sizeHint( )` after adding each new widget. It seems that QWidgets (including QFrames) only update their `sizeHint( )` when the children widgets are "visible". Somehow, in some occassions Qt sets new children to "not visible" when they are added, don't ask me why. You can see if a widget is visible by calling `isVisible( )`, and change its visibility status with `setVisible(...)`. I solved my problem by telling to the QFrame that they new child widgets were intended to be visible, by calling `setVisible( True )` with each of each child after adding them to the QFrame. Some Qt fundamentalists may say that this is a blasphemous hack that breaks the fabric of space time or something and that I should be burnt at the stake, but I don't care, it works, and it works very well in a quite complex GUI that I have built.